# Randomise across columns for half a dataset

Tags: r, neural-network, row

I have a data set for MMA bouts.

The structure currently is

```
Fighter 1, Fighter 2, Winner
x             y          x 
x             y          x
x             y          x
x             y          x
x             y          x
```

My problem is that Fighter 1 = Winner so my model will be trained that fighter 1 always wins, which is a problem.

I need to be able to randomly swap Fighter 1 and Fighter 2 for half the data set in order to have the winner represented equally.

Ideally i would have this

```
Fighter 1, Fighter 2, Winner
x            y         x
y            x         x
x            y         y
y            x         x
x            y         y
```

is there a way to randomise across columns without messing up the order of the rows ??

Comment: You have shown only 1 row in your data, hows does it get translated to 5 rows?

Comment: Why is row 3 (`Fighter 1 = "x", Fighter 2 = "y", Winner = "y"`) in your expected output repeated in row 5? Ditto for duplicate rows 2 and 4.

Comment: Thats just a sample of what my data looks like I have 4800 rows of fight data, 
I edited the question there

Comment: @KilianMurphy Huh? That doesn't really answer the question. How does one row get expanded to give 5 rows? Why the duplicate rows? It seems to me you should take a look at `expand.grid` (or `tidyr::crossing`).

Comment: x and y just represent fighter names, I need to be able to swap the names randomly from columns Fighter 1 and Figther 2 for half the data set

Comment: @KilianMurphy Still not an answer. **How** do you expand rows? If you swap entries in `Fighter 1` and `Fighter 2` why do you end with **duplicate entries** (rows 2+4 and 3+5 are identical)? Please re-read the comments above carefully, and then edit your main post to provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your `x`s and `y`s are arbitrary and just placeholders. I'll further assume that you need the `Winner` column to stay the same, you just need that the winner not always be in the first column.

Sample data:

```r
set.seed(42)
x <- data.frame(
  F1 = sample(letters, size = 5),
  F2 = sample(LETTERS, size = 5),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
x$W <- x$F1
x
#   F1 F2 W
# 1  x  N x
# 2  z  S z
# 3  g  D g
# 4  t  P t
# 5  o  W o
```

Choose some rows to change, randomly:

```r
(ind <- sample(nrow(x), size = ceiling(nrow(x)/2)))
# [1] 3 5 4
```

This means that we expect rows 3-5 to change.

Now the random changes:

```r
within(x, { tmp <- F1[ind]; F1[ind] = F2[ind]; F2[ind] = tmp; rm(tmp); })
#   F1 F2 W
# 1  x  N x
# 2  z  S z
# 3  D  g g
# 4  P  t t
# 5  W  o o
```

Rows 1-2 still show the `F1` as the `W`inner, and rows 3-5 show `F2` as the `W`inner.

Answer (score -1):

I also found that this code worked

```
matches_clean[, c("fighter1", "fighter2")] <- lapply(matches_clean[, c("fighter1", "fighter2")], as.character)

changeInd <- !!((match(matches_clean$fighter1, levels(as.factor(matches_clean$fighter1))) -
                  match(matches_clean$fighter2, levels(as.factor(matches_clean$fighter2)))) %% 2)


matches_clean[changeInd, c("fighter1", "fighter2")] <- matches_clean[changeInd, c("fighter2", "fighter1")]
```